# Run FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0

Tags: json, firebase, github, npx

So I have been stuck with this issue for days and I am going mad soon.

I have tried EVERYTHING, but still cant get through commit/push to my GitHub repo.

```
  [2024-02-11T14:18:11.731Z] SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0
      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
      at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/home/runner/.npm/_npx/ba4f1959e38407b5/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:375:43)
      at ReadStream.emit (node:events:517:28)
      at ReadStream.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1400:12)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
  
  Error: Failed to authenticate, have you run firebase login?
  
  The process '/usr/local/bin/npx' failed with exit code 1
  Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/npx' failed with exit code 1
  {
    conclusion: 'failure',
    output: {
      title: 'Deploy preview failed',
      summary: "Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/npx' failed with exit code 1"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have reauthenticated, added secret key from firebase to github, adding    env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_EXPERIMENTS: webframeworks, .gitignored, installing packages, trying AI, nothing and I mean NOTHING works

Comment: Seems like no one can help...